# How to echo something when in infinite while loop?

Tags: php, infinite-loop, shared-hosting

*For example I have something like this :*

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  set_time_limit(0); 
  ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

  while(true) :
    echo microtime(true)."<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush(); 
    sleep(1);
  endwhile;

  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

This code works on my `localhost` and each second on the page is printed `microtime()`, but when I try to run same script on my `Shared Linux Hosting` nothing is printed, page just has infinite loading time.

**How to print something when in infinite loop, on my hosting?**

*Maybe I have to enable /disable something in my `php.ini` file? any Ideas?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Gzip waiting for all the data, so it can compress and send it.

As you're on shared hosting, it might be a bit tricky to disable this completely.
So we can either:

**Disable Gzip on the Linux hosting by using either PHP**

```
ini_set('output_buffering','on');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0)
```

**Disable Gzip by using .htaccess**

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

**EDIT:**
Could you also try this out on your Linux Host?

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','on');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ob_implicit_flush();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
      echo $i;
      echo str_repeat(" ", 500);
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
}
?>
```

This one works on my host, it'd be interesting to see if it works on yours.

Comment: I edited and checked my php5.ini file and added that line to .htaccess, but it still don't display anything

Comment: Have a look at my edit, I posted a working piece of code I just tested out on my host.

Comment: It displays results only after page is loaded.

Comment: I've got the same issue on a GoDaddy shared hosted web server and (unfortunately), this solution does not work for me. ob_flush() and flush() are completely ineffective. Output is not displayed until the script finishes execution. I only have issues on this one server (the only shared hosted server I use). I tried both of the solutions in your answer (the ini_set() function calls and the .htaccess file). The same problem still occurs. While I cannot guarantee I will keep this page up, here is the URL for the page where it happens: http://www.specpro.us/.admin/specpro.us.reqcert.php?debug=1